# Unexpected values within for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, variables, behaviorsubject

I'm absolutely perplexed as to why the variable end does not change throughout the looping process. Although I successfully increment the variable j, it does not change the value of the variable end that contains a piece of code referencing the variable j. Can someone please help me with this?

```js
const numbers = [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 10, 88];

function moveZeros(arr) {
  const lastIndex = arr.length - 1;
  let j = 0;
  let end = arr[lastIndex - j];

  for (let item of arr) {
    console.log(end); // odd behavior 
    console.log(j++); // behaves as expected 
  }
  console.log(end) // odd behavior
}
console.log(moveZeros(numbers));
```

Comment: well, you never update `end` value inside the loop, so it won't change, you just log it, never make anything else with `end` variable, so it's not odd, it's expected. You probably want to move end assingment to inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't changes because you never update the value of `end` inside the loop:

```js
const numbers = [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 10, 88];

function moveZeros(arr) {
  const lastIndex = arr.length - 1;
  let j = 0;
  let end = arr[lastIndex - j];

  for (let item of arr) {
    end = arr[lastIndex - j]; // Changes value of end
    console.log(end); // odd behavior 
    console.log(j++); // behaves as expected 
  }
  console.log(end) // odd behavior
}
console.log(moveZeros(numbers));
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const numbers = [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 10, 88];

function moveZeros(arr) {
  const lastIndex = arr.length - 1;
  let j = 0;
  let end = (j)=>{arr[lastIndex - j]};

  for (let item of arr) {
    console.log(end(j)); // odd behavior 
    console.log(j++); // behaves as expected 
  }
  console.log(end) // odd behavior
}
console.log(moveZeros(numbers));
```

That code already happened. You need it to happen now to get current value...